# Failed to fetch & Some index files failed to download

Tags: apt, updates

I am getting the following string of errors when running `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Ign:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                     
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                      
Ign:3 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise InRelease                                   
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                       
Ign:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise InRelease                                      
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/burg/ubuntu xenial InRelease                      
Ign:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise InRelease                                      
Get:9 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release [11,9 kB]                                  
Hit:10 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise Release                                       
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/macbuntu/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security InRelease [55,7 kB]                  
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/os-patches/ubuntu xenial InRelease                 
Get:15 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release.gpg [72 B]                                
Ign:15 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release.gpg                                       
Hit:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu xenial InRelease   
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial InRelease               
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu xenial InRelease                   
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-updates InRelease [55,7 kB]
Hit:17 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise/main Sources                                      
Ign:17 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise/main Sources                       
Hit:19 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise/main amd64 Packages                              
Ign:19 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise/main amd64 Packages  
Ign:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial Release
Hit:20 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise/main i386 Packages   
Ign:20 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise/main i386 Packages   
Hit:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-backports InRelease
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages    
Hit:17 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise/main Sources                                     
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Hit:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release          
Hit:19 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise/main amd64 Packages        
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Hit:20 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise/main i386 Packages
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en     
Ign:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons 
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages     
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages      
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages       
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US  
Ign:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en     
Ign:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons 
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages     
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages      
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages       
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US  
Ign:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en     
Ign:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons 
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages     
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages      
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages       
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US  
Ign:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en     
Ign:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:29 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:31 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 123 kB in 35s (3.456 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: The repository 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/versable/elementary-update/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What do these errors mean, and how can I fix them?

My `sources.list` file content is

```
#############################################################
################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
#############################################################

###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/users/320386/arronical iam using elementary OS kernel ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Unfortunately questions about Elementary OS are not supported here. Ask Ubuntu only supports questions about official flavours of Ubuntu OS. There is a specific ElementaryOS stack exchange site where this question would be considered on-topic on the [ElementaryOS SE](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

From your `apt-get update` output I can see that you've `precise` repositories in Xenial, which is the source of the problem. You should remove those lines from your `sources.list` file.

1. First open the file using this command in a terminal

   ```
   sudo -i gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Then remove all lines that have `precise` in it.
3. Then save the file and exit gedit. Now do `sudo apt-get update`.

The problem should be gone.

Comment: cant you speak indonesian

Comment: No. I don't speak indonesian. Do you have problem understanding the answer?

Comment: Which Should be eliminated

Comment: no, i understand you speak

Comment: You'll see many lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. You will remove every line that has `precise` word in it

Comment: can you edit sources,list in aboove?

Comment: @NORRISRAHMAN are you using Ubuntu 12.04 or 16.04 ?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04