# Can't install anything. Terminal shows 404 errors

Tags: apt, updates, repository

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2DzP.jpg) of my situation.  I've clicked off all the repos and tried `sudo apt-get update` but I still receive:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried the suggestions in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298177/a-failed-to-fetch-error-occurs-when-apt-get-update-is-run-how-do-i-fix-this) and only made it through the second one. I think it disabled the [main software repos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4anv.jpg) for me. I enabled them and now I still have the same problem and can't install apps. In Ubuntu Software Center, I tried installing Krusader and nothing happened. When I type terminal commands,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install krusader
```

this is what happens:

```
sudo apt-get install krusader
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package krusader
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Is your network ok?

Comment: I can browse the internet just fine. I haven't had issues downloading and installing apps in the past. This issue only occurred in the last few weeks I think. EDIT: I'm connected by wifi and ethernet cable to an access point but it's been that way for years.

Comment: Have you tried to edit your sources.list and change the location for example like 

http://(Change this to another geography location)/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-armhf/Packages

in my case: http://mirror.0x.sg - Singapore
find the location that is not very far from your location

then run sudo apt-get update see if it works for you

Comment: I went to Software & Updates > Ubuntu software> and found/selected the closest server. Nothing changed. Maybe it really is my local network?

Comment: If it means anything, I installed Gufw Firewall several months ago. It's been disabled this entire time though.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues like this, couldn't fetch files from the Ubuntu server, this might help it worked with me, Go to **software & updates** > **Ubuntu software**> **Re** choose the closest server. Now Try `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Nothing changed :(

Comment: hey can you try this, this might work https://askubuntu.com/questions/836532/failed-to-fetch-some-index-files-failed-to-download

Comment: if you want to restore the default repos , https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories